# Apex Scheduler - CronTrigger gets created but doesn't run

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, cron

We are running into an issue with the Apex Scheduler.
We've scheduled some code to run every half hour. Since the ".schedule()" method only allow to run code hourly,
we call the method twice as follow:

```
System.schedule('Hourly TaskCron 1', '0 0 * * * ?', new TaskCron());
System.schedule('Hourly TaskCron 2', '0 30 * * * ?', new TaskCron());
```

The classe declaration is as follow:

```
global class TaskCron implements Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {

    }
}
```

However, we're running into an issue where the CronTrigger get created but the code doesn't run.

The only thing we can see is that it goes from state = `'WAITING'` to state = `'DELETED'`.

This seems to happen randomly one or twice a day. The next CronTrigger runs correctly.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: There are two possible issues. First, when we do this we use the cron expressions "0 0 * * * ? *" and "0 30 * * * ? *". Second, are you sure your TaskCron correctly implements `Schedulable`?

Comment: Can I suggest you [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/319018/edit) your question to provide the skeleton of your TaskCron implementation, showing the class declaration and the related method declaration - no need for the content of the execute method.

Comment: I added the class declaration as you suggested. We tried both syntax for the cron expressions but there was no improvement.

Comment: It all looks right (note you only need to use "global" if you are wanting to expose the class across a package boundary), so not sure what's going wrong.